# Unresolved overloaded function type when using a template friend function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-function

I have a problem where I'm trying to stuff a friend function of a class template into a `boost::function`:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>

template <int N>
struct Vec{
   friend
   double dot(Vec, Vec){}
};

template class Vec<2>; //Force multiple instantiations
template class Vec<3>;

int main()
{
    boost::function<double  (Vec<2>, Vec<2>)> func = dot;
    double (*func1)(Vec<2>, Vec<2>) = dot;
}
```

Neither of the two lines in `main` will compile. For the first one, GCC complains:

```
error: conversion from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to non-scalar type 'boost::function<double(Vec<2>, Vec<2>)>' requested
```

The error for the second line seems even more confusing to me:

```
error: no matches converting function 'dot' to type 'double (*)(struct Vec<2>, struct Vec<2>)'
testtmpl.C:6:15: error: candidates are: double dot(Vec<2>, Vec<2>)
testtmpl.C:6:15: error:                 double dot(Vec<3>, Vec<3>)
```

I'm kind of stymied since I don't see why `double dot(Vec<2>, Vec<2>)` doesn't match.

Any ideas as to what is happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my understanding, if a friend function is defined in a class without other
corresponding declarations, the friend name can be looked-up only through ADL.

§7.3.1.2/3 says:

> The name of the friend is not found by simple name lookup until a
>   matching declaration is provided in that namespace scope

The code will be able to be compiled by adding corresponding
function declaration

`double dot(Vec<2>, Vec<2>);`
like
[here](http://ideone.com/wKE6A).

Comment: +1 This makes sense. I was thinking on this last night and I discarded for some reason, but it does actually make sense. Since the original code is already doing explicit instantiations, having to *declare* all the functions should not be a problem. Another alternative is creating a templated free function of static member function that will perform the dispatch (`dot` will be internally accessible through ADL).

Comment: Indeed, I suppose this friend name look-up is one of the most confusing
rules in C++.
I tore out my head when I first heard this explanation :)

Comment: As any popular C++ author/guru ever recommended to always declare a function prior to making it a friend? (I seem to recall something about function *template* friends.) This is a rule of thumb of mine but I have no idea if it solves a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
template <int N> struct Vec;

template <int K> double dot(Vec<K>, Vec<K>) { return 0; }

template <int N>
struct Vec
{
  friend double dot<>(Vec<N>, Vec<N>);
};
```

GCC 4.6.1 actually gave a very helpful warning:

```
warning: friend declaration ‘double dot(Vec<N>, Vec<N>)’ declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)
```

Comment: The semantics of this piece of code are slightly different than the original. If there are implicit conversions from *anything* to `Vec<N>` those will not be applied, since overload resolution for the template requires *perfect* matching of the arguments.

Comment: Well, kind of... it defines a friend function for each instantiation of the template, the function is defined inline... that is a fairly common piece of code. Think that the friend function might be called `operator<<` for one common example.